# SSL Certificates are about to expire. What should I do?

Tags: iis, ssl, iis-6, ssl-certificate, certificate

I have two SSL Certificates setup on two domains on my IIS6 Server. One certificate is through godaddy, and the other is through my host (1and1).

Do I need to *renew* these or do I need to buy new ones and replace the old certificates?

My only experience with SSL Certificates is when I set them up 11 months ago in the first place... so I know very little.

Also, I'd like to switch the GoDaddy Certificate over to 1and1. Would that be hard to do?

Furthermore, Both certificates are attached to e-commerce stores that would appreciate uninterrupted operation during normal business hours.

Thanks in advance for your time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should renew the 1an1 certificate and buy a new one for the godaddy certificate from 1and1 - i don't believe you can renew certs from other vendors - although it wouldn't hurt to ask.

Once you get the new certs you can replace the old ones, your services should not be affected as long as the info is correct. There is no "Good On" type check for certs just "Good Until" checks.

Comment: When you have to buy something and have little idea what you're buying, you need a salesperson.

Comment: Any idea how I go about renewing a certificate? I looked over their website and Googled it... I can't seem to distinguish between a renewal and just slapping a new one over the old one.

Comment: The only real difference between a renewal and a new one is they generally give you a discounted price on the renewal. You still have to gen the CSR and send it to them, they then gen you a new cert with a new expiration date.

Comment: Not always true.  Some certificate vendors will give you an updated certificate with a new expiration date without generating a new CSR.